# Keep a button disabled until user reach the end of a text paragraph in Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material, modal-dialog

I'm using `MatDialog` of `Angular Material` to display a text paragraph and a button at the end.
How to keep the button disabled until the user scroll down and reach the bottom end of that paragraph using Angular / JavaScript ?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the `scroll` event:

```
<mat-dialog-content (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  all your content here...
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button [disabled]="buttonDisabled" mat-button>OK</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

and the TS:

```
buttonDisabled = true;

onScroll(ev: any) {
  if (ev.target.offsetHeight + ev.target.scrollTop >= ev.target.scrollHeight) {
    this.buttonDisabled = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the HTML

```
<mat-dialog-content (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  all your content here...
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button [disabled]="buttonDisabled" mat-button>OK</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

in the TS

```
onScroll(ev: any) {
if (Math.ceil(ev.target.getBoundingClientRect().height) + ev.target.scrollTop >= ev.target.scrollHeight) {
  this.data.buttonDisabled = false;
} }
```

i using this code to get height of dialog content

```
Math.ceil(ev.target.getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using intersection observer.

Hardy based in this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067679/is-there-a-function-to-update-the-variable-of-the-selected-item-after-scrolling/75075315#75075315)  we can write (I repeat the inView function)

```
  obs$!:Observable<boolean>
  @ViewChild('scrollArea') set _area(value:any){
    
    this.obs$=this.inView(value.nativeElement,1).pipe(filter((x:any)=>x))
  }
  inView(element: Element, threshold: number) {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        ([entry]) => {
          subscriber.next(entry.isIntersecting);
        },
        {
          root: null,
          threshold: threshold,
        }
      );
      observer.observe(element);
      return () => observer.disconnect();
    });
  }
```

We need only use in our button

```
<button [disabled]="!(obs$|async)">You got the final</button>
```

And add at end of the scrollable text

```
<span  #scrollArea></span>
```

See [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eyptiu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

This also works using a mat-dialog ([another stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jzeayu?file=src%2Fmain.ts))