# Is there a function to update the variable of the selected item after scrolling by mouse/arrow keys in Angular?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, scroll, dropdown, ngfor

I am making an image selection area in my angular web app.

It shows one image at a time, and I want my 'selectedImage' variable to be updated everytime a scroll or keydown.arrowup/down is being made through the image list.

I also want the selection area to show the previously-selected image on website load. I can get the index of the image from the array but I dont know how I can tell the browser to pre-scroll the list to the pre-defined position on component init.

I am using *ngFor to stack images from an image array, and I am limiting the display area to show only one image at a time by modifying overflow-x & y properties and css scroll-snap.

```
<div
    class="picture-scroll-container"
        (scroll)="onScroll($event)"    
    >
        <div
            class="indiv-image"           
            *ngFor="let pict of pictArrayfromDB; let i = index"
                 
            (click)="onPictureSelected(pict.pict_name, i)"
        >
            <div>              
            <img [src]="pict.graphic_image_base64" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
.picture-scroll-container {
  height:50px
  width:65px
  background-color: white;
  
  flex: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: monospace;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.indiv-image {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

Currently the variable only updates when I click it after scrolling to the item. But considering some users dont click it after scrolling, is there a way to update the variable after I scroll to it?

(scroll) only registered the scroll event but not the pict.pict_name.

Thanks so much

Comment: Could you slightly improve the focus of your question? Is what you are asking how to make the browser scroll to a location?

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to check "when an element are in viewport" it's use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

The best way to mannagge I see is from this [Netanel Basal entry](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-directive-functionality-lazy-344a4bd9434b)

Well, we are going to change a bit the directive in the before article

```
export class IntersectionObserverDirective implements OnInit {
  public observable: Observable<any>;
  
  @Input('intersectionObserver') data = null;
  constructor(
    public el: ElementRef,
    @Optional() @Inject('INTERSECTION_PERCENT') private percent: number
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.observable = this.inView(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      this.percent !== null ? this.percent / 100 : 1
    );
  }

  inView(element: Element, threshold: number) {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        ([entry]) => {
          subscriber.next(entry.isIntersecting);
        },
        {
          root: null,
          threshold: threshold,
        }
      );
      observer.observe(element);
      return () => observer.disconnect();
    });
  }
}
```

I choose that we can use a provider to indicate the "threshold" (the percent to make the observable emit the value) because "sound good" that all the directives in one component have the same threshold. If we don't use any provider, the percent is 100% (that's, the element should be view entery in the viewport)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: 'INTERSECTION_PERCENT', useValue: 50 }],
})
```

So, we can asign to any tag this directive, e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let i of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]">
  <p [intersectionObserver]="i" [class.selected]="i == selected">
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
  </p>
</div>
```

Now we can get all the `IntersectionObserverDirective` using ViewChild and subscribe to a merge of the observables of the directives, well really not to the observable else a observable filter only values true and map to the "data" of the directive

```
  subscription: any = null;
  selected: any;
  @ViewChildren(IntersectionObserverDirective)
  intersections: QueryList<IntersectionObserverDirective>;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.subscription = merge(
      ...this.intersections.map((x) =>
        x.observable.pipe(
          filter((res) => res),
          map((_) => x.data)
        )
      )
    ).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.selected = res;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6bwpyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fintersection-observer.directive.ts) to see how a "paragraph" change the class