# Does someone know how to implement snap scrolling in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, scroll, scroll-snap, scroll-snap-points

My page consists of 3 components: "navbar", "product details" and "footer" as it shows in the picture.

[page structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdulE.png)

As you can see product details component has 3 sections. Each of them except first one (100vh - 4.5rem) has height of 100vh.

I want to use snap scrolling on each section in product details (when i scroll down to half of the first section it scrolls automatically to sections two e.t.c).

In pure html and css code you need to apply properties connected with parent-child relationship:

HTML:

```html
      <div class="parent">

        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>

      </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.parent{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child{
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Does someone know how to apply snap scrolling on sections in Angular?
Thank you in advance.

I want the effect: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I feel you're looking for `scroll-snap-type: y proximity;` in parent, see [docs in mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type)

Comment: thanks @Eliseo but in know how scroll-snap-type works in pure css/html. Im struggling with implementing this using angular :(

Comment: Angular can use .css. If you want to use a kind of "intersection observer", check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067679/is-there-a-function-to-update-the-variable-of-the-selected-item-after-scrolling/75075315#75075315)